# XSP Editor Toolbar takes up entire screen

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

Anyone seen this before?  Opening xPages and custom controls in the XSP editor and the toolbar masks the entire screen.  Have no idea how to get rid of it.  Happens in all db's.  Ran repair on the designer installation, uninstalled and re-installed to no avail. I can open via Package Explorer and the XML editor. [image]

Comment: Does menu "Windows / Reset Perspective..." repair it?

Comment: Nope.  Already tried that.

Comment: Toolbar preferences, does unchecking "Show toolbar that applies to my current task" have any effect?

Comment: It does not have any effect.

Comment: Try shutting down all notes/designer windows, finding your data folder, and renaming the workspace folder to workspace.old. You will lose all eclipse customisations, opened applications & worksets, and probably other things.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks!